# Apache RewriteRule not working – page not found

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have no idea why it doesn't work, /spelling/30000 gives the Not Found page. Please help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /?mod=spelling&word=$1 [PT]
RewriteRule ^$ /?mod=spelling [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Considering that index.php file is the one which is taking traffic in backend for internal rewrite rules. Please make sure to keep your `.htaccess` file along side with index.php file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?mod=spelling [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?mod=$1&word=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @KennyRomanov, make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.